# Does Dart have a concept of class variables?

Tags: dart

While going through [A Tour of the Dart Language](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) I see this example in the [Constructors](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) section:

```
class Point {
  num x, y;

  Point(num x, num y) {
    // There's a better way to do this, stay tuned.
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Talking about instances variables. Coming from Python this initially confused me a little as I though `num x, y;` would be kind of class variables.

Does Dart have a concept of class variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "class variables".
I assume you mean static variables.

Static variables exist once per class, while instance variables exist once per instance.

```
class Point {
  static num x, y;

  fooMethod() {
    print('$x, $y');
  }
}
```

With in the class where they are declared, they can be accessed without a prefix.
From everywhere else they are accessed using the lass name as prefix where they are declared.

```
void main() {
  print(Point.x);
}
```

Also from subclasses the class prefix where the fields are declared are required because they are not inherited.

```
class CustomPoint extends Point {

  barMethod() {
    print('${Point.x}, ${Point.y}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep I meant this. So "static" keyword does the magic. Cool. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is even in the Tour just somehow did not get it: "Use the static keyword to implement class-wide variables and methods."

Comment: Static variables are not quite the same as class variables, but are the closest thing in Dart. Library variables might also be interesting to look at.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Dart static variables are different from Python class variables? Is it just because Python, like Java, allows accessing static/class variables through an instance?