# Instance member 'incrementTracker' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: function, flutter, dart, static

i am learning the flutter and i am facing this issue. I create the function in the class, when i try to call that function in the text button it gives me error can't be using static access.

**Class code:**

```
class QuizStore {
  int _tracker = 0;

  void incrementTracker() {
    if (_tracker < _quizzy.length) {
      _tracker++;
    }
  }
}
```

**When I call it:**

```
onPressed(){
  setState((){
   QuizStore.incrementTracker(); 
 });
}
```

**The error I get:**

```
void incrementTracker()
package:quiz/quizbank.dart

Instance member 'incrementTracker' can't be accessed using static 
access.dart(static_access_to_instance_member)
```

)

Thanks in advance for solving this.

Comment: You have to initialize QuizStore to access any variables or functions inside it. I suggest learning dart OOP from articles or youtube before jumping right into flutter. To initialize a class, simply add `()` to the Class -> `QuizStore()`

Comment: As Uni correctly pointed out this is because of `instance` and `class` variables. Just wanted to add this link here for more info. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Dart have a concept of class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966609/does-dart-have-a-concept-of-class-variables)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're referring to a Class instead of a Class Object.

The following code should be able to solve the issue, hope this helps! Cheers

```
onPressed(){
  setState((){
    QuizStore().incrementTracker(); 
  });
}
```